# Trigger with current date query/where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date, triggers, shapes

we want to create a trigger which checks if a new measurement (=messung) point lies within the current glacier shape (=umriss).

are tables look like this:

**glacier shape (=Umriss)**

```
create table umriss
(
 umr_nr       number (4) not null,
 umr_datum    date,
 GLST_ID      number (4) not null,
 shape        mdsys.sdo_geometry,
 GLETSCHER_ID number (3) not null
)
;

alter table umriss
add constraint umriss_glst_pk
primary key (umr_nr, GLST_ID, GLETSCHER_ID)
;

ALTER TABLE umriss 
ADD CONSTRAINT umriss_gletscherstand_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (GLST_ID, GLETSCHER_ID) 
REFERENCES GLETSCHERSTAND(GLST_ID, GLETSCHER_ID);
```

**new measurement (=Messung)**

```
CREATE TABLE MESSUNG
(
 MESS_NR      number (4) not null,
 MESS_DAT     date,
 MESS_AKK     number (20) NOT NULL,
 MESS_SCHMELZ number (20) NOT  NULL,
 SHAPE        mdsys.sdo_geometry,
 MESS_BILD    blob,  
 KMPGN_NR     NUMBER (4) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE MESSUNG
ADD CONSTRAINT messung_pk
PRIMARY KEY (MESS_NR);

ALTER TABLE MESSUNG
ADD CONSTRAINT messung_messkampagne_fk
FOREIGN KEY (KMPGN_NR)
REFERENCES MESSKAMPAGNE(KMPGN_NR);
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER MESSUNG_in_UMRISS_TRI
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MESSUNG
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
   num_check NUMBER;
BEGIN 
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO num_check
     FROM UMRISS u
    WHERE mdsys.sdo_contains (u.shape, :NEW.point) = 'TRUE';

   IF num_check <> 1
   THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (=20500, 'Messung in keinem Umriss')
   END IF; 
END;
```

How do we iplement the function so the trigger only checks within the most curretn glacier shape?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What column on UMRISS defines "most recent"?

Comment: "umr_datum    date" -> there you have a date for every shape and from that you should be able get the most current one...somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the one row fron UMRISS which matches the most recent date in the table.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO num_check
FROM UMRISS u
WHERE mdsys.sdo_contains (u.shape, :NEW.point) = 'TRUE'
AND u.umr_datum = ( select max(d.;umr_datum) from UMRISS d );
```

This sort of query is the price for keeping historical data in teh same table as the current record.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that POINT ist not defined in your example?

However, you might consider a check constraint because a trigger would only be enforced when a MESSUNG record is inserted or updated, but not when UMRISS is changed

```
alter table MESSUNG add constraint MESSUNG_CC_CONTAINS check(mdsys.sdo_contains (shape, point) = 'TRUE')
```

In case you're frequently updating the UMRISS records it might not be feasable at all to enforce such a constraint because Oracle would have to check all MESSUNG records when UMRISS is updated or deleted. Perhaps consider an additional mapping table between MESSUNG and UMRISS that you can update separately.